# How to access a <div> stored in an array in React?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs

I want to access a particular property of a div where a number of div is stored as as an array.

```
 ans[i] = (
  <>
    <div
      className="gantt1"
      key={arrivalTime[i]}
      style={{
        background: getColor(i),
        color: `white`,
        width: getWidth(i) + `%`,
      }}
    >
      P{i}
    </div>

    <div className="time_container">
      <div className="gantt_time">
        <div className="timeDisp">{calcualteBurst(i)}ms</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
);
```

I want to change the value of   `<div className='timeDisp'>{calcualteBurst(i)}ms` this later. So how can I access this particular property and modify it later in React?

Comment: You want to change the value of _what_? Divs don't have a value property. Do you mean the included text? That's what React props are for.

Comment: Can you post the full context of this code? You shouldn't be accessing single elements and making modifications in React like you would with jQuery. A change to your component data should trigger a re-render of the component template, which would make the change in the HTML

Comment: If your objective is to style that particular `div` differently, you may use conditionals for `className` like so: `<div className={(i==2} ? "timeDisp2" : "timeDisp">`. Also the array-element `ans[i]` holds a fragment `<> ...... </>` and I'm unsure if __a number of div is stored as as an array__ is accurate.